# Are there internal strings for the biometric prompt?

Tags: android, string, android-biometric-prompt

I'm trying to develop a Library which use a biometric prompt, but some of the methods required is the setTitle, setSubtitle and the NegativeButtonText.

open BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder
setNegativeButtonText(@NonNull negativeButtonText: CharSequence)
Required: Sets the text for the negative button on the prompt.

open BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder
setSubtitle(@Nullable subtitle: CharSequence?)
Optional: Sets the subtitle for the prompt.

open BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder
setTitle(@NonNull title: CharSequence)
Required: Sets the title for the prompt.

The app that will use my library has a lot of languages, but all things inside my library haven't any relation with any string, but the Biometric Prompt is one which need them.

So, my question is if there are systems strings to avoid me to introduce several languages only for 3 parameters. Something like android.R.string.biometric_title, or something.

Or I need to implement all these strings.xml inside my library?

Thank you